# Call ftok from java using JNA (on remote session)

Tags: java, jna, ftok

When I try to call ftok from java using JNA every time I get different key for the same file path and id parameters. Is there some reason in ftok implementation or/and in JVM working mechanism that cause this situation? In native code it's fine - same key fro same parameters.

This is how looks my method in java code:

```
NativeLong ftok(String path, int id);
```

How can I solve this problem?

Seems that problem only occurs on remote session, otherwise it's fine.
What might be the reason and if there is any solution?

Comment: Look at the result value in hex.  Can you see any pattern in the results?

Comment: Yes, there is a pattern, here are few sample results:
0x421c82bd
0x421f82bd
0x422182bd

Comment: If you make the call three times in succession, do you get different results?  What exactly do you mean on "remote session"?  If this is happening internal to a web request, and you have one `ftok` call per request, it's entirely possible that the resource you're accessing is specific to the request and not globally unique/available on the system itself.